# Formatting What's returned from LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

So, I currently have a LINQ query

```
BStops.JPPlatforms.Platform
  .Where(Stop => Stop.Name.ToLower().Contains(SearchBox.Text.ToLower()))
  .Select(Stop => new { Stop.Name, Stop.PlatformNo })
  .ToList();
```

[image: Query results]

Which is returning the data I expect it to, the property Platform contains a list of stops that hold another class with properties I want to access to such as Name, PlatformNo and PlatforTag, now the killer for me is two things, one is less important at the moment but if you can help it would be great!

So I want to format this output so when you search it doesn't have all this garbled stuff around it, I would prefer it to be like

```
Annex Rd near Railway (50643)
```

I've tried adjusting my query to be like

```
BStops.JPPlatforms.Platform
  .Where(Stop => Stop.Name.ToLower().ToString().Contains(SearchBox.Text.ToLower().ToString()))
  .Select(Stop => String.Format("{0} ({1})",new { Stop.Name, Stop.PlatformNo }))
  .ToList();
```

But that causes it to crash back to a unhanded exception, for the life of me I can't seem to figure this out, as for the second part. I'd also like my LINQ query to search both the Name and PlatformNo properties I've already tried the logical || but it crashes back to an unhanded exception and I don't know enough about LINQ to figure out why, any help at this point would be great :).

Comment: Remove the `new {` and the following `}` so you pass the name and number to `string.Format` instead of one anonymous class.

Comment: `BStops.JPPlatforms.Platform.Where(Stop => Stop.Name.ToLower().ToString().Contains(SearchBox.Text.ToLower().ToString())).Select(Stop => String.Format("{0} ({1})",Stop.Name, Stop.PlatformNo)).ToList();` ? If so, that crashes it back to unhanlded execption

Comment: Ah, right Async programming. It was trying to read from a list that wasn't populated. added a try catch to display a messagebox and it seems to work fine once the list is populated, thank you good sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your LINQ query to this would solve the problem.

```
BStops.JPPlatforms.Platform.Where(Stop => Stop.Name.ToLower()
                                                   .Contains(SearchBox.Text.ToLower()))
                           .Select(Stop => new 
                                           { 
                                               StopAddress = $"{Stop.Name} {Stop.PlatformNo}" 
                                           })
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: Did the formatting for you, however all you needed to do on mobile is add 4 spaces before the start of the line and make sure there is a blank line before it.

Comment: Juharr, beat you to it, both solutions work pretty well, but now I need to figure out why my program crashes when I try use || to compare to things.

Comment: Thanks @Scott. I got it now.

Comment: Where you are trying to use || ?

Comment: `BStops.JPPlatforms.Platform.Where(Stop => Stop.Name.ToLower().Contains(SearchBox.Text.ToLower().ToString()) || Stop.PlatformNo.Contains(SearchBox.Text.ToString())).Select(Stop => String.Format("{0} ({1})", Stop.Name, Stop.PlatformNo)).ToList();`

Comment: You mentioned that it crashes. What error you are getting when it crashes?

Comment: It was that the List it's returning has nothing in it, even though it should since without the `||` when I search Wainoni the correct data comes back but when I add the `||` clause it crashes even when using Wainoni as a test case again, something to do with how it's doing the or is killing what gets returned.

Comment: The where clause in your linq looks ok to me. It should filter the results properly. Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, I've moved it around a bit but for now until I can think of anything or anyone knows I'm going to continue with development.

Answer (score 0):

The `Where` clause is not performant.  The `Text.ToLower` should be done outside of the Linq.  Also `ToLower` returns a string, so there is no need go call `ToString`

The `Select` should not create a new object.

```
var text = SearchBox.Text.ToLower();
BStops.JPPlatforms.Platform
  .Where(stop => stop.Name.ToLower().Contains(text))
  .Select(stop => String.Format("{0} ({1})", stop.Name, stop.PlatformNo))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: I've already made that chnage, now I am trying to figure out how I can have an or in the query without it thinking nothing exists no matter what I try use as a test case.

Comment: It is really strange that || operator not giving the results. Are you getting data from the database using EF or any other ORM? Did you try testing the code by populating the collection of platform manually? If you are using ORM try to see the query being executed on the db when you run this LINQ? In case of ORM I am pretty sure that the SQL query being executed on the db is not proper which causes no data to return.

Comment: I create the same class and populated a collection of manually in console application and try to filter using a search value and it worked without any problem. So if in-memory collection works fine then there is something to do with the backend and the query being executed.

Comment: Obviously `BStops.JPPlatforms.Platform` is not returning any data.  Check the code, because I can't.